# C: Socket Read Stalling Execution

Tags: c, sockets, io

I'm implementing a custom FTP application and am having some trouble reading/saving a file from the server to the client. I have an implementation as follows:

```
fp = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
int bytes_written, bytes_read;    
while(1) {
    bzero((char *)&buf, sizeof(buf));
    bytes_read = read(s, buf, sizeof(buf)); // s is correctly configured socket of server implementation
    if(bytes_read==0) // where i thought reading is finished
        break;
    if(bytes_read<0)
        // error checking, exit(1)

    void *p = buf;
    while(bytes_read > 0) {
        bytes_written = write(fp, p, bytes_read);
        if(bytes_written<=0)
            // error checking, exit(1)
        bytes_read -= bytes_written;
        p += bytes_written;
    }
}
```

My understanding was that once there is no more data to read, bytes_read would be 0 and I would break from the loop. However, after reading and writing the correct amount of bytes in my test, the program stalls after calling read again. I can't print bytes_read after that point and the execution does not continue into the bytes_read if statements. Am I misusing the control flow logic somehow?

Comment: What *is* `buf`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And you do remember that sockets are by default *blocking*? And that `read` returns `0` *only* when the connection is closed by the peer?

Comment: The `read()` call will return 0 when no more bytes are available **and** an end of file condition is detected.  For a network connection, end-of-file is not detected until the connection is actively closed, which is sensible because until then, you can never be certain that the remote host won't send something more.

Comment: I read the documentation probably 5 times over, not sure how I missed the return requiring the connection to be closed. So for a persistent FTP application, the client must connect, download a file, close connection, and then reconnect before attempting another action?

Comment: I assume you're downloading the file after having sent `RETR` command to your FTP server.

To know how much bytes have to be downloaded, just sent `SIZE` command before to know when to stop.